# Is there any way to redirect the output of native JVM output like -XX:+PrintCompilation

Tags: java, debugging, jvm-hotspot, sun

Some hotspot JVM flags, like `-XX:+PrintCompilation`, cause output to appear on stdout or stderr.  GC related output, such as that enabled by -verbose:gc, can be redirected using `-Xloggc:<path>`, but I can't find any way to redirect other native output, other than by redirecting the entire process (which may be undesirable for certainly reasons, such as also capturing all System.out output).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+PrintCompilation uses `print_on(tty, message)`, as can be seen from [openjdk source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/code/nmethod.cpp), printing directly to tty, so I'd think redirecting the entire process output is your only option without recompiling the compiler.